# Angular2 Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I'm trying to DELETE some data from my Database I have this method:

```
public deleteMessage(id: string): void {

    // Url = localhost/messages/id
    let url = `${Config.baseUrl}/${Config.messages}/${id}`;
    console.log("url", url);

    this.dataService.deleteData(url).subscribe(
        // success
        data => {
            console.log(data)
        },

        // error
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );

}
```

Which uses uses a dataService for the http delete:

```
public deleteData(url: string, headers?): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.delete(url, headers)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: any) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
}

private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
        error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server   error';
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

But I always get: `DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.`

Comment: You need that to configure on the server. Search for the error message and also CORS.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have already in my node server the following `app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });;`

Comment: But not `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` as the error message indicates.

Comment: @thanks Gunter as always you are a big help. please include answer to upvote and accept your answer